# Search for special characters and character space

Tags: text-processing, grep, csv

Hello I am currently working with a csv file.

I want to find a bash command that will help me find special characters

```
 ?, !, #, *, %
```

and also and character spaces such as

```
' '
```

any advice would be helpful, I am looking at potentially using the grep function but not too sure how this would apply to the above specifications.

Comment: What do you want to do with them once you find them? Print them? Remove them? Replace them with some other char? Print the line they occur on? Print the field they occur in? Something else? Please [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input (with those characters in-context surrounded by other characters) and the expected output given that input.

Comment: @jixubi  only space or whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, enclose the characters you want find within a [Bracket Expression `[...]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html).

```
grep '[?!#*% ]' infile
```

there are some exceptions like:

- if `^` character: it can be place anywhere in `[]` but not first character, because `^` character at first negates the characters within its bracket expression.
- if `]` character: it should be the first character, because this character is also used to end the bracket expression.
- if `-` character: it should be the first or last character, because this character is also can be used for defining the range of characters too.

---

Depends on your need that want perform on the found characters:

1. Print only those characters if exist

   ```
   grep -o '[?!#*% ]' infile
   ```
2. Remove those characters:

   ```
   tr -d '[?!#*% ]' < infile              ##or
   sed 's/[?!#*% ]//g' infile             ##or
   awk '{ gsub(/[?!#*% ]/, "") }1' infile
   ```
3. Replace them say with a single space:

   ```
   tr '[?!#*% ]' ' ' < infile             ##or
   sed 's/[?!#*% ]/ /g' infile            ##or
   awk '{ gsub(/[?!#*% ]/, " ") }1' infile
   ```
4. Replace with some other string:

   ```
   sed 's/[?!#*% ]/someString/g' infile   ##or
   awk '{ gsub(/[?!#*% ]/, "someString") }1' infile
   ```
5. Print the entire line that at least one of them occurred in a line:

   ```
   grep --color=none '[?!#*% ]' infile    ##or
   sed '/[?!#*% ]/!d' infile              ##or
   awk '/[?!#*% ]/' infile
   ```
6. etc.

Answer (score 1):

To find any line matching at least one of the characters you mentionned:

```
grep '[ !?#*%]' file.csv  # looks for space, !, ?, #, *, %  into file.csv and shows matching lines
```

Be careful : some characters need to be at a specific place (ex: "[a-c]" looks for "a, b or c", and not "a, - or c")

You should also specify the locale grep will work in. Usually: C locale. This helps prevent a specific locale (for ex variants of utf-8) to mess up the range, if any, specified.

To look for "any line matching any character other than : letters or numbers or comma" into a csv file (assuming it is using comma as separator, otherwise just change the separator you actually use):

```
LC_ALL=C grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9,]' file.csv
  # and if you also accept doubleqhotes in that csv:
LC_ALL=C grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9,"]' file.csv
  # and if instead of comma you use TAB as a separator
LC_ALL=C grep "[^a-zA-Z0-9$$(printf '\t')]\"" file.csv
  -or-
LC_ALL=C grep "[^a-zA-Z0-9$$(printf '\t"')]" file.csv
```